# Java NoSuchMethodError when using the "Run Project" function in NetBeans

Tags: java, caching, netbeans, nosuchmethoderror

I have a big Java project, where I added a new method (which involves many files in many packages).

When I compile and run the project via javac in MingW, it works. So no problem with my code.

When I use the "Clean and Built" function from NetBeans, I can run the generated class files or the generated jar file - works as well.

But (!) if I use the "green arrow" button in NetBeans (standing for "Run Project"), I get the java.lang.NoSuchMethodError error. How can I fix this problem?
I already deleted the NetBeans cache, but still the same.

// UPDATE:
I just found the reason: I accidentally included the git.jar as a library, so NetBeans used the methods in the jar file instead of my new methods.

Comment: do you use libraries?, this might be a version problems classes compiled with different versions

Comment: I use libraries, but they are unchanged since I started the project and it worked all the time until now.

Comment: check the javac version in MingW and one used by netbeans, might be the library are compiled with javac in MingW, so it might have issues with one used by netbeans

Comment: Netbeans' _Clean and build_ starts an external maven build with a classpath different from the one the IDE uses itself.